# image size for UIImages, 1024 x 1024?

Tags: ios, xcode, image, image-processing, uiimage

Apples docs state:

> You should avoid creating UIImage objects that are greater than 1024 x
>   1024 in size. Besides the large amount of memory such an image would
>   consume, you may run into problems when using the image as a texture
>   in OpenGL ES or when drawing the image to a view or layer. This size
>   restriction does not apply if you are performing code-based
>   manipulations, such as resizing an image larger than 1024 x 1024
>   pixels by drawing it to a bitmap-backed graphics context. In fact, you
>   may need to resize an image in this manner (or break it into several
>   smaller images) in order to draw it to one of your views.

I assume this means that if we are working with non-square images, we should break them into smaller images? Is there any specific documentation or explanations on this, or does anyone have any any tips from experience?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Note that for iPad 3 graphics, this no longer holds due to the screen's 2048x1536-physical-pixel size.

Comment: Despite the iPad 3's screen size, it's still a very good strategy to do your image processing on tiles. I work on a system that does this on the Mac where we have lots of VRAM and very high limits on texture sizes. But we tile some things anyway. And it has nothing to do with images being square or not, either. Just size. So what are you trying to do? It's hard to give advice if we don't know what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On the pre-A5 iOS devices, the maximum OpenGL ES texture size was 2048x2048 (Apple's documentation is incorrect in this regard by saying it's 1024x1024). What that means is that you can't have an image larger than that in either dimension. The newer iOS devices (iPhone 4S, iPad 2, iPad 3) have a maximum texture size of 4096x4096.

It does not mean that you have to have square images, just that an image must not have its width or height exceed 2048 (again, 4096 on newer devices). If you try to do so, I believe your image will just render as black.

This used to be a limitation for all UIViews not backed by a CATiledLayer, but I believe they now do tiling on large enough views automatically. If you need to work with an image larger than 2048x2048, you'll need to host it in a CATiledLayer or the like.

The memory cautions are worth paying attention to, though. Images are stored in their uncompressed form in memory, no matter their source, so you're looking at 16,777,216 bytes per 2048x2048 image (4 bytes per pixel for RGBA). That can add up pretty quickly, if you're not careful.

Comment: Where did you get this information from? I'd like to put a 640 pixel by 1136 pixel (320 points by 568 points with scale = 2) UIImage in a UIImageView to use as a full-screen background for a 4-inch retina iPhone screen, but the 1136 pixel dimension is just a little larger than the documented 1024-pixel limitation. If the real limitation is 2048 pixels, I won't have to split the UIImage and UIImageView into two.

Comment: @user2135004 - I've tested various sizes, and the hard cutoff does appear to be 2048 pixels in either dimension for the older devices (4096 for the newer ones). Smaller views work fine, but ones with pixel sizes larger than this go black if they're not backed by a tiled layer of some kind. This corresponds directly to the maximum texture size, which you can query via OpenGL ES.

Comment: You can query a device's maximum texture size at run time with OpenGL using something like `glGetIntegerv(GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE, &maxTextureSize)`. Aside, the [UIImage documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage) as of iOS 10 no longer seems to mention any size restrictions.