# iOS app memory increases on loading image (5 MB) on image view

Tags: ios, iphone, memory-management, uiimageview, automatic-ref-counting

I am trying to load an image (5.4 MB) of resolution 4923 x 9405 on an image view. There is a drastic increase in the memory allocation of my app as soon as i load the image. The memory allocation before loading the image was around 17 MB, whereas it reaches 198 MB when i load my image on the image view. I was assuming that my app should consume a memory of 5 MB only while loading the image which proved to be wrong when i analysed the memory allocations of my app.

My Questions

- **Why does my iOS app shows such behaviour?**
- **Is there any way to identify, what will be the actual memory allocation of the app when any such large images are loaded?**

You can check the attached screenshots for memory allocations before loading the image and after loading the image.

[image: Memory allocation before loading the image]

[image: Memory allocation after loading the image]

Comment: Without showing the code that is loading the image your question is pointless.

Comment: There is not much operations on the image or image view. I simply displayed the app which was stored in document directory.

Here is the code...
//_strFpPath is the path where the image is stored in document directory.

UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:_strFpPath];
myImageView.image = img;

Comment: `imageWithContentsOfFile` loads the image at the path specified, but does no cache (despite of imageNamed),  Don't you call `imageWithContentsOfFile` several times in your code?

Comment: @teamnorge I guess in this case, my issue is the memory allocation while loading the image on image view instead of the method to make image view object. Also i have a single image view on a screen, so it hardly matters if i cache the image. What do you say?

Comment: You should probably read the second paragraph of the UIImage documentation. It specifically says "You should avoid creating UIImage objects that are greater than 1024 x 1024 in size. Besides the large amount of memory such an image would consume..."

Comment: @l'L'l I know that i am crossing the limits that were recommended by apple (FYI someone is saying its 2048x2048, not 1024 x 1024 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12031704/image-size-for-uiimages-1024-x-1024) . But my question is why such huge memory is allocated while loading image of size 5 MB. I want to understand what actually happens when my image is loaded on image view.

Comment: If you read the question/answer you just linked then you should know the answer. Images on disk are compressed, but once loaded into memory it's typically not —  (a rough memory allocation estimate can generally be calculated by image width * height * 4) = total bytes in memory. Working off that it would show loading an image 4923 x 9405 will consume around 185 MB or so of memory.

Comment: @RahulMathur Did you get any solution for your problem. I discovered this issue just today when the memory hike is about 80mb for a 4mb image.